# Add doubleclick on jQuery Easyzoom plugin on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I want to implement [jQuery Easyzoom](http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/) with double click on mobile devices.

On desktop monitors everything is fine, user hovers image and it applies easyzoom plugin and zoom image. But on mobile devices, image is almost 100% width and height so if a user wants to scroll down it activates zoom on image instead scrolling down.

Is there any possibility to allow Easyzoom on mobile devices (window.width <= 767px) via double clicking image.

```
var page_width = $('body').innerWidth();

if (page_width >= 768) {
    var easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom({
        loadingNotice: 'Loading image...',
        errorNotice: 'Error while loading image!'
    });

    var api = easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom').data('easyZoom');
} else {
    // doubleclick JS code for easyzoom
}
```